# Múltiplas conexões via rtsp usando OpenCV e Python

Tags: python, script, socket, opencv, rtsp

Recentemente fiz um script básico em Python usando a biblioteca OpenCV para reconhecimento  usando camêras de segurança, porém percebi que por algum motivo, não consigo abrir duas ou mais conexões na mesma camêra, utilizando o mesmo script.

Script utilizado:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://link")
while True:
    try:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("camera", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Quando executo o script na primeira vez, ele abre normalmente uma janela com a imagem da camêra, porém quando deixo esse script executando e tento executar novamente, obtenho esse erro no exception:

> OpenCV(4.1.2)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in
>   function 'cv::imshow'

Como posso permitir que o script abre mais janelas ao executa-lo? Se for uma limitação do hardware, como posso contornar a situação?

Lembrando que se eu pego o link rtsp da camêra e abro em outros softwares, consigo abrir várias janelas com as imagens da camêra, somente com esse script obtenho o erro ao tentar executar novamente com ele sendo executado.

**Update**

Depois de procurar um pouco na internet, vi que recomendam usar socket para poder ter um servidor pegando a imagem da camera e quando os clientes conectam no servidor via socket, a imagem da camera é mostrada.

Server.py

```
import base64
import cv2
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://link")  # init the camera

while True:
    try:
        _, frame = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
        encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
        footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Client.py

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5554')

while True:
    try:
        frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
        img = base64.b64decode(frame)
        npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
        source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
        cv2.imshow("Stream", source)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Porém o problema agora é quando tenho mais de um client conectado no server, obtenho a resposta:

> Address in use

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Verifica se o path para o seu arquivo está correto pq parece que ele não está achando a imagem\video. Se estiver usando `\` no path, use o escape `\\`

Comment: Acredito que não seja esse o problema, pq o script funciona normalmente, só não consigo manter duas conexões abertas.

Answer (score 0):

Deduzo que estás a tentar correr vários clientes na mesma máquina, certo?

Um socket no servidor é listado num único porto, [dá aqui uma vista de olhos para mais info](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/tcpip-ports-sockets/). Todas as ligações de clientes estabelecidas nesse servidor estão associadas ao mesmo porto, no lado do servidor da ligação. 
Uma conexão estabelecida é identificada exclusivamente pela combinação de pares IP/porto do lado do cliente e do servidor.
Várias conexões no mesmo servidor podem compartilhar o mesmo par IP/porto do lado do servidor, desde que estejam associadas a diferentes pares IP/porto do lado do cliente, e o servidor possa lidar com tantos clientes quanto os recursos disponíveis do sistema permitirem.

No lado do cliente, é prática comum que novas conexões de saída usem um porto aleatório no cliente, ou vê o código abaixo que partilho para verificar um porto disponível. Utilizando o random, e nesse caso, é possível ficar sem portos disponíveis se fizeres muitas ligações num curto período de tempo.

Ou utilizar o seguinte código para obter o porto disponível, [fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

port = 8000
while True:
    try:
        httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(('', port), Handler)
        print 'Serving on port', port
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except SocketServer.socket.error as exc:
        if exc.args[0] != 48:
            raise
        print 'Port', port, 'already in use'
        port += 1
    else:
        break
```